# CSS Display table hides other cell when resized at media query breakpoints

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

this is about responsive image gallery website with different image sizes with no margins/paddings. my problem is that the .showcase class is hiding at @media breakpoint when resizing but I want to display all the images.

**HTML**

```
<a href="album.php?album_id=' . $row['album_id'] . '" class = "showcase" >
<img src = "' . $row['album_thumb'] . '">
<div class="label-container">
<h3 class = "title">' . $row['album_title'] . '</h3>
<p class = "desc"> ' . $row['album_desc'] . '</p>
</div>
</a>'
```

the output of this will be

```
<div class="row">
<a class="showcase">...</a>
<a class="showcase">...</a>
<a class="showcase">...</a>
</div>
```

**Normal Size and CSS Below**

> img1 | img 2 | img3
>
> img4 | img 5 | img6

```
.content{
    width:100%;
    display:table;
}
.row{
    display:table-row;
}
 .showcase{

 display:table-cell;
 position: relative;
 width:33.333333%;     background-color: #000;
 vertical-align: middle; 
 }
```

**Breakpoint 1 and CSS**

> img1 | img2
>
> img4 | img5
>
> @media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
>       .showcase{
>           width:50%; } }

**Breakpoint 2 and CSS**

> img1
>
> img4
>
> @media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
>       .showcase{
>           width:100%;
>       } }

after the breakpoint 2, only 2 images will be displayed. i've used display:block; and float:left; before but the images stack vertically sometimes because they have different sizes. what should be the corrent approach for this? message me if you want to see the real thing. thank you in advance.

Comment: add 'display:inline-block' instead of 'display:table-cell'

Answer (score 1):

add `display:inline-block` instead of `display:table-cell` in your css.